# How to run AWS Sagemaker Studio job based on pre defined schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

Currently I am developing a model in AWS Sagemaker Studio. In Sagemaker there are multiple options for running model, like notebook instance, sagemaker studio etc, to schedule a task in notebook instance, it is known that we need to use AWS lambda for that. But I can't see an documentation on how to run scheduled job on AWS Sagemaker Studio.

Need suggestion on this. I know this is not a good question based on StackOverflow guidance like showing some code, but the problem itself is a bit new one, with a newer solution like AWS Sagemaker Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new feature allows you to [Operationalize your Amazon SageMaker Studio notebooks as scheduled notebook jobs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/operationalize-your-amazon-sagemaker-studio-notebooks-as-scheduled-notebook-jobs/)